# Parse Ordnance Survey SPARQL GET request in R

Tags: r, xml, geometry, sparql, geospatial

i'm a bit new to this subject matter so bear with me;

I am accessing the [Ordnance Survey SPARQL Endpoint](http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/datasets/os-linked-data/explorer/sparql) for their RDF data from R. I am having trouble parsing the returned GML geometry attribute.

My SPARQL query (for this e.g.) returns the geometry of Edinburgh South Electoral Constituency with a couple of attributes (name, code and URI);

```
require(SPARQL)
require(XML)

endpoint <- "http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/datasets/os-linked-data/apis/sparql"

query <- paste0( 
"PREFIX geom: <http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/geometry/>
PREFIX geog: <http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/admingeo/>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>

SELECT ?WestminsterConstituencyName ?gssCode ?uri ?g
WHERE 
{ 
?uri a geog:WestminsterConstituency;
skos:prefLabel ?WestminsterConstituencyName;
geog:gssCode ?gssCode;
geom:extent ?geom .
?geom geom:asGML ?g.
}
HAVING(?WestminsterConstituencyName=\"Edinburgh South\")")
```

In R, i want to extract and map these results in leaflet. I currently have two ways of obtaining the results from the query above;

1. Using GET request via the httr package and make XML data;

   ```
   packs <- c("sp","stringr","rgdal","leaflet","gsubfn","XML","SPARQL","plyr","RColorBrewer","utils","httr")
   lapply(packs, require, character.only = TRUE)

   #format the request properly to return XML
   request <- paste0("http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/datasets/os-linked-data/apis/sparql?query=",URLencode(query, reserved = TRUE),"&output=xml")

   #GET request from the endpoint and parse to XML
   data <- GET(request)
   data.xml <- xmlParse(content(data,"text"))
   ```
2. Using SPARQL package to return a dataframe;

   ```
   # set endpoint URL and pass query to it, just keeping the results
   qd <- SPARQL(endpoint,query)$results
   ```

When using either method, the geometry returned (either as XML variable or dataframe column) has all the GML tags:

```
"<gml:Polygon><gml:outerBoundaryIs><gml:LinearRing><gml:coordinates>LONG LIST OF COORDINATE PAIRS</gml:coordinates></gml:LinearRing></gml:outerBoundaryIs></gml:Polygon>"^^<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#XMLLiteral>
```

When using method no.2, i can perform the following workaround to create a polygon, but it seems very ugly;

```
# BNG proj4 string
BNG <- "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs"

# extract data to attach to SpatialPolygonDataFrame later
data <- qd[,!(colnames(qd) == "g")]

# extract geometry part of results
geom <- qd[,"g"]

# use various gsub and split functions to create a dataframe of X and Y
geom.sub <- sub(".*<gml:coordinates> *(.*?) *</gml:coordinates>.*", "\\1", geom)
s <- strsplit(as.character(geom.sub), ' ')
coords <- data.frame(coords=unlist(s))
coords[] <- lapply(coords, as.character)
l <- strsplit(coords$coords, ",")
df <- ldply(l)
colnames(df) <- c("x", "y")
df[] <- lapply(df, as.numeric)

# create Polygon(s)
geom.list <- Polygons(list(Polygon(df)),1)
final <- SpatialPolygons(list(geom.list),proj4string=CRS(BNG))
final.df <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(final,data)
```

Method 1 returns an XML file like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sparql xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#">
  <head>
    <variable name="WestminsterConstituencyName"/>
    <variable name="gssCode"/>
    <variable name="uri"/>
    <variable name="g"/>
  </head>
  <results>
    <result>
      <binding name="WestminsterConstituencyName">
        <literal>Edinburgh South</literal>
      </binding>
      <binding name="gssCode">
        <literal>S14000024</literal>
      </binding>
      <binding name="uri">
        <uri>http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/id/7000000000033932</uri>
      </binding>
      <binding name="g">
        <literal datatype="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#XMLLiteral">&lt;gml:Polygon&gt;&lt;gml:outerBoundaryIs&gt;&lt;gml:LinearRing&gt;&lt;gml:coordinates&gt;LOTS OF COORDINATE PAIRS HERE&lt;/gml:coordinates&gt;&lt;/gml:LinearRing&gt;&lt;/gml:outerBoundaryIs&gt;&lt;/gml:Polygon&gt;</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
  </results>
</sparql>
```

But i have NO idea how to make either polygons (writable to shapefiles) or even JSON from the XMl result. I'd prefer to work with XML as i'd like to access other XML resources as well.

Furthermore, is the processing on method 2 (stringsplitting etc) really viable? what is the data doesnt always conform? Will information on multi-part polygons be lost? (i think it will). Is there a more 'proper' method?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: ok, i'm learning a little more, this is a SPARQL XML format. Requires specific work.

Comment: this returns empty list; getNodeSet(data.xml,"//ns:head",c(ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results")). Why?

Comment: Should `data <- GET(test)` in **Obtaining Results 1.** be `data <- GET(request)` ?

Comment: Are you using `http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/datasets/os-linked-data/apis/sparql` as your endpoint?  Is `SPARQL(endpoint,query)` working for you?  I'm getting an error `'1: xmlParseEntityRef: no name'...`  Do OS queries have to come from the UK?

Comment: @Mark Miller, yes to your first comment, apologies

Comment: @Mark Miller, to your 2nd comment; yes, exactly that address for the endpoint. I've edited my script to show it (thanks). Try loading in the XML package? though i wouldn't think you have to. I was querying the OS endpoint from Belgium the other week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this sticks to your interest in (plain vanilla?) XML, but it does draw a map.  I parameterized the WestminsterConstituencyName, so you could even turn this into a function.

I didn't know anything about GML, but **I decided to use it as-is, instead of parsing the coordinates out into something more generic like a data frame.**  After some research, I felt confident that rgdal could serve as a bridge between the GML data from OS and the inputs expected by leaflet.  **The string conversion within the SPARQL just eliminated the need to remove quotation marks and the string literal typing within R.**  I suspect that rgdal *might* be able to do something directly with the GML polygon from the OS, but wrapping the polygon into some GML defining a layer and a feature was clearer to me.

A reasonable next step would be trying to use a text connection for readOGR, so you don't need to save and then open a file.

Here's a [Shiny implementation](http://phaseocore.phaseolus.biz/osleaflet/).  I haven't attempted any performance improvements like caching.

```
require(SPARQL)
require(XML)
require(leaflet)

# requires some system libraries
# I followed this for ubuntu
# http://www.sarasafavi.com/installing-gdalogr-on-ubuntu.html
# might also need to do something like
# sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev libproj-dev
library(rgdal)

WestminsterConstituency <- "Edinburgh South"

endpoint <-
  "http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/datasets/os-linked-data/apis/sparql"

query <- paste0(
  "PREFIX geom: <http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/geometry/>
  PREFIX geog: <http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/admingeo/>
  PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>

  SELECT ?WestminsterConstituencyName ?gssCode ?uri (str(?g) as ?gstr)
  WHERE
  {
  ?uri a geog:WestminsterConstituency;
  skos:prefLabel ?WestminsterConstituencyName;
  geog:gssCode ?gssCode;
  geom:extent ?geom .
  ?geom geom:asGML ?g.
  }
  HAVING(?WestminsterConstituencyName='",
  WestminsterConstituency,
  "')"
)

qd <- SPARQL(endpoint, query)$results

xmlres <-
  xmlTreeParse(qd$gstr, asText = TRUE, useInternalNodes = TRUE)

template.text <- '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ogr:FeatureCollection
xmlns:ogr="http://ogr.maptools.org/"
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
<gml:featureMember>
<WestminsterConstituency fid="0">
<ogr:geometryProperty>

</ogr:geometryProperty>
</WestminsterConstituency>
</gml:featureMember>
</ogr:FeatureCollection>'

# some node adding ideas from
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35201830/r-insert-node-into-xml-tree-at-specific-location
template.xml = xmlTreeParse(template.text,
                            useInternalNodes = TRUE,
                            asText = TRUE)
template.top = xmlRoot(template.xml)

name.node = newXMLNode("NAME", WestminsterConstituency)

template.node = xmlElementsByTagName(el = template.top,
                                     name = "WestminsterConstituency",
                                     recursive = TRUE)

addChildren(template.node[[1]], kids = list(name.node))

template.node = xmlElementsByTagName(el = template.top,
                                     name = "geometryProperty",
                                     recursive = TRUE)

addChildren(template.node[[1]], kids = list(xmlres))

saveXML(template.top, 'expanded.gml')

if ("GML" %in% ogrDrivers()$name) {
  WC <-
    try(readOGR(dsn = 'expanded.gml', layer = "WestminsterConstituency"))
  if (class(WC) != "try-error")
    summary(WC)
}

# http://www.alex-singleton.com/R-Tutorial-Materials/7-converting-coordinates.pdf
ukgrid  <-  "+init=epsg:27700"
latlong  <-  "+init=epsg:4326"

# http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123212/assign-crs-to-shapefile-in-r
proj4string(WC) <- CRS(ukgrid)
WC.LL <- spTransform(WC, CRS(latlong))

m <- leaflet()
m <- addTiles(m)
m <- addPolygons(data = WC.LL, map = m)
m
```

Comment: thanks a lot, ulitmately i was going to put this through Shiny but it seems you beat me to it!

Comment: and thanks for the XML parsing on the geometry variable, interesting that you made it a string in the SPARQL query. I didnt think to parse the individual variable. I'm going to hold off accepting the answer until i've had a test but it looks good, cheers

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I edited the answer to add some of my reasoning, including the string conversion within SPARQL.  Let us know how things go for you!

Comment: i've finally revisited this after a busy month. I can't get Shiny to re-draw polygons from a drop down choice, i get "Don't know how to get path data from object of class reactive". any clues?

Comment: i should say i've written this problem up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40800962/leaflet-shiny-cannot-draw-reactive-polygons